# iFrame wont will parent container

Tags: css, xaml

I have an `absolute` positioned div with an iFrame inside (doesnt work for silverlight objects either). For some reason it doesnt expand to fill its parent, which it should.

If you replace the iframe with a div with the same ID it works correctly.. Whats the problem?

```
<div id="rightpanel">
    <iframe id="silverlightControlHost" src="http://google.com"></iframe>
</div>

#rightpanel {
    background: green;
top: 32px;
left: 190px;
bottom: 0;
padding: 20px!important;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 0px;
overflow: auto;
min-width: 700px;
}

#silverlightControlHost {
    background: red;
border: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZfG3g/

Answer (score 2):

sticking the following on the iframe seems to work (in the fiddle at least anyway):

```
#silverlightControlHost {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    ... rest of your css ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZfG3g/1/

Comment: @Seer: Well that wasn't the case when I used a div, but you're right.

Comment: Interest.. I swear I tried this (multiple times) and it didnt work.. but now it does!

Answer (score 0):

you may try this 
you forget to mention iframe **width and height** 
check the below code this is covering the full parent block

```
<div id="rightpanel">
    <iframe id="silverlightControlHost" src="http://google.com" width="740" height="630"></iframe>
</div>
<style>
#rightpanel {
    background: green;
top: 32px;
left: 190px;
bottom: 0;
padding: 20px!important;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 0px;
overflow: auto;
min-width: 700px;
}

#silverlightControlHost {
    background: red;
border: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}</style>
```